# Sort Json by props of child elements (table of comparison)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I am trying to display a table with a comparison of some items. The idea is to sort in the correct way (less on the left and more complete on the right) like:

```
             Plan1  |  Plan2  |  Plan3
item1           X        X         X
item2           -        X         X
item3           -        -         X
```

But the API of our vendor serves the json unordered. The problem is that we have more than 100 items and almost 20 plans, so its impossible to filter in the "hardcode" way.

The json is colossal, so the simple version with just the minimum would be (like this example):

```
[
    {
        "Id": "1",
        "Name": "Item1",
        "Plans": [
            {
                "PlanMaster": "EPTV Max",
                "IdPlan": 1000,
                "HasPlan": true
            },
            {
                "PlanMaster": "EPTV",
                "IdPlan": 1001,
                "HasPlan": true
            },
            {
                "PlanMaster": "Web TV",
                "IdPlan": 1002,
                "HasPlan": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "2",
        "Name": "Item2",
        "Plans": [
            {
                "PlanMaster": "EPTV Max",
                "IdPlan": 1000,
                "HasPlan": false
            },
            {
                "PlanMaster": "EPTV",
                "IdPlan": 1001,
                "HasPlan": true
            },
            {
                "PlanMaster": "Web TV",
                "IdPlan": 1002,
                "HasPlan": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": "3",
        "Name": "Item3",
        "Plans": [
            {
                "PlanMaster": "EPTV Max",
                "IdPlan": 1000,
                "HasPlan": false
            },
            {
                "PlanMaster": "EPTV",
                "IdPlan": 1001,
                "HasPlan": false
            },
            {
                "PlanMaster": "Web TV",
                "IdPlan": 1002,
                "HasPlan": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The point is, how can I navigate through the json to query few things like "How many plans I have", "List plans in order of fewer itens to more", etc...

how is this kind of "sort"/"comparison" problem called? I tried to google sorting, etc... and could not find much. I just want to know how can I query the nodes in javascript so I would be able to implement the logic.

cheers

Comment: You'll have to create your own sort algorithm/logic, encapsulated in the [.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) array method, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could treat the plans as binary number and use it as sort criterion.

```js
var data = [{ "Id": "1", "Name": "Item1", "Plans": [{ "PlanMaster": "EPTV Max", "IdPlan": 1000, "HasPlan": true }, { "PlanMaster": "EPTV", "IdPlan": 1001, "HasPlan": true }, { "PlanMaster": "Web TV", "IdPlan": 1002, "HasPlan": true }] }, { "Id": "2", "Name": "Item2", "Plans": [{ "PlanMaster": "EPTV Max", "IdPlan": 1000, "HasPlan": false }, { "PlanMaster": "EPTV", "IdPlan": 1001, "HasPlan": true }, { "PlanMaster": "Web TV", "IdPlan": 1002, "HasPlan": true }] }, { "Id": "3", "Name": "Item3", "Plans": [{ "PlanMaster": "EPTV Max", "IdPlan": 1000, "HasPlan": false }, { "PlanMaster": "EPTV", "IdPlan": 1001, "HasPlan": false }, { "PlanMaster": "Web TV", "IdPlan": 1002, "HasPlan": true }] }];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getRange(o) {
        var r = o.Plans.reduce(function (r, a) {
                return r * 2 + !a.HasPlan;
            }, 0);
      
        o.r = r; // just to show what's happen
        return r;
    }

    return getRange(a) - getRange(b);
});

console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I put few more itens in different order and it sorted correctly. Thanks Nina!

Answer (score 1):

You can define a generic function that sorts an array based on some `key` function:

```
let sortBy = (a, key) => a
    .map(x => [key(x), x])
    .sort((x, y) => x[0] > y[0] ? 1 : x[0] < y[0] ? -1 : 0)
    .map(x => x[1]);
```

then write some task-specific key functions, for example:

```
let numberOfPlans = item => item.Plans.filter(x => x.HasPlan).length;
```

and pass them to `sortBy`:

```
let sortedData = sortBy(data, numberOfPlans);
```

Another (and perhaps better) option would be to load that data into a relational database (e.g. sqlite) and use the whole power of SQL to retrieve whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use a loop either way. If your JSON is as big as you're making it out to be, efficiency is an issue. You need to do everything you can to increase efficiency.

However, if your JSON has 100 items (as you say) this really isn't that big of a data set. A data set with millions of rows? Sure. But a hundred or even a few thousand probably won't pose much of a perf issue regardless (obviously that is also a product of how many nested properties are in each item of your dataset it as well).

As far as 'navigating" the JSON, you need to simply loop through them as objects and avoid as many accessors as you can (cache lookups, etc).

I'm rarely a fan of hard-coding checks where a loop would be better, but keep in mind for perf that in some cases doing so is acceptable if you absolutely know what your data set is, and the perf benefits outweigh the maintenance benefits.

An example of something that is more perf-friendly but less maintenance-friendly:

```
var i;
var j;
//Set up a 2-dimensional array where each array index represents the number of plans that each of it's members has. In this case, numPlans[0] contains all items that contain 0 plans, etc.
var plans = [[], [], []];
//Don't re-create variables on every loop, just re-assign
var item;
var numPlans;
var p;

for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ 
    item = data[i];
    p = item.Plans;
    numPlans = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
        if(p[j].HasPlan) {
             numPlans++;
        }
    }
    plans[numPlans].push(item);
}
```

This isn't tested, but it's a rough-draft fairly perf-oriented approach.